# fmt : format a float/double without format string

Tags: fmt

I would like to format a single double/float to a string/wstring with fmt.
something like
std::string s = fmt:format_??(my_float);

Since the formats I use are kind of fixed, is there a way to use the library without having to use the format string, but directly feeding the settings?

I noticed there are *format_int* and *format_float* that uses a settings struct,which may be suitable, but these are inside the detail namespace and also it's not so clear how to initialize the input parameters.

My (unbenchmarked) guess is that avoiding the format string would result in a faster conversion.

Any idea or experience in this regard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to use the library without having to use the format string, but directly feeding the settings?

No but if the format is known at compile time you can use [format string compilation](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#compile-api) which completely eliminates the runtime overhead of handling a format string, however small. For example:

```cpp
std::string s = fmt::format(FMT_COMPILE("{}"), 42);
```

is the fastest method of converting a number into an `std::string` (there is also `fmt::to_string` which is equivalent): https://www.zverovich.net/2020/06/13/fast-int-to-string-revisited.html.